# zip files of a certain date to zip file with batch

Tags: datetime, batch-file, time, zip, 7zip

I'm trying to do a batch file to run every day. The batch needs to zip all the files with the current system date.

I have the following for now and it's working but is zipping all the files.

```
@echo off
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\test\location_zip\zip_file_%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%" "C:\test\*.*"
pause
```

Can someone please help me to zip only the files created with system date instead all?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a 7-zip solution. But with WinRAR this can be very easily achieved:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRar.exe" a -ac -afzip -agYYYY-MM-DD -ao -cfg- -ed -ep1 -inul -m5 -r -tn24h "C:\test\location_zip\zip_file_" "C:\test\*.*"
```

**a** ... add files to archive.
**-ac** ... clear archive attribute after compression.
**-afzip** ... create a ZIP archive instead of a RAR archive.
**-agYYYY-MM-DD** ... append current date to archive file name in format YYYY-MM-DD.
**-ao** ... add only files with archive attribute set.
**-cfg-** ... ignore configuration file and RAR environment variable.
**-ed** ... do not add empty directories.
**-ep1** ... exclude base directory from names, i.e. `C:\test\`
**-inul** ... disable all error messages.
**-m5** ... use best compression method.
**-r** ... recurse subdirectories.
**-tn24h** ... add only files with a last modification date within last 24 hours (newer than 24 hours).

A single license of WinRAR is very cheap and includes unlimited upgrades. The few dollars/euros for a WinRAR license are invested well taking into account the time needed to code a batch file for archiving purposes with free 7-zip because of missing features which WinRAR has since more than 10 years. (I bought my WinRAR license in 1999 and have never needed any other compression tool.)